# call object with UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having a situation now that I get error whenever I call a object.

I have these codes in my TaskCustomCell.swift

```
class TaskCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_dept: UILabel!
}
```

And I wanted to call this class from another class.
I used let test:TaskCustomCell = TaskCustomCell()
but I get error from this.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What was the error buddy?? was it unable to find TaskCustomCell ?

Comment: which object you want to call and exactly where?

Comment: When I run the application, it stated Thread1:breakpoint1.1

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: hi @rmaddy i have solved the breakpoint but then i get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION for test.lbl_name.text = "hello"

Comment: Use the link I posted to find the cause of the crash.

Comment: okay. but i wanted to know is it the correct way that i call a object like this?  let test:TaskCustomCell = TaskCustomCell()

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the crash is caused by using following line of code:

```
let test:TaskCustomCell = TaskCustomCell()
test.lbl_name.text = "hello"
```

It will crash because, you have only got the reference to the `TaskCustomCell()` but not its *XIB/View*. Means that you are assigning the value to the Label that is not being drawn yet.

Comment: then what should i do? any recommendation or reference that i can refer to?

Comment: where are you using this cell. in which view controller and why?

Comment: hi @Mr.UB it cannot be solved. but finally i found a solution for it. sorry for the late reply.